# How do I run hello world program in openCL?

Tags: c++, opencl, ubuntu-18.04

I wrote my first program in OpenCL. But I can't run the program, because
fail assertion platforms size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

//#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_2_0_APIS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

using utyp = unsigned int;
constexpr utyp SIZE = 100000000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    std::vector< cl::Platform > platforms;
    const auto retGet = cl::Platform::get( &platforms );

    std::cout << "retGet == " << retGet << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Platforms.size == " << platforms.size() << std::endl;

    assert( platforms.size() > 0 );
    // etc
```

I use kubuntu 18.x.

Thank you for any help.
Best Regards.

Continue...

I have access to source cl::Platform::get:

```
static cl_int get( VECTOR_CLASS<Platform>* platforms)   {
    cl_uint n = 0;
    if( platforms == NULL ) {
        return detail::errHandler(CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE, __GET_PLATFORM_IDS_ERR);
    }

    cl_int err = ::clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &n);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return detail::errHandler(err, __GET_PLATFORM_IDS_ERR);
    }
    //etc
```

::clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &n) return -1001.

I can't find any description value -1001 in the documentation. :/

Comment: It looks like `cl::Platform::get` returns an error value or `SUCCESS`. Can you check the error?

Comment: I modified above code. cl::Platform::get return -1001.

Comment: Do you have access to API documentation? I don't know anything about open cl except what my google fu tells me. Normally you compare error codes against a known list of values and take action appropriately. Does your documentation say what possible values `get` can return?

Comment: The cl::Platform::get call ::clGetPlatformIDs ( https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html ). The ::clGetPlatformIDs should return CL_SUCCESS OR CL_INVALID_VALUE. The CL_INVALID_VALUE is equal -30, but in my program return -1001 :/

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I had to install packages from this site:

https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/blob/master/DISTRIBUTIONS.md